# Blank response message from JQuery .ajax() call is 13 characters in length?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using JQUERY .ajax() to send serialized form data to MySQL using PHP. The backend PHP being called will return a message if there was an issue processing the data. My Javascript function then checks for a message being returned before deciding what to do next. If the message length is '0', then the post was successful and it can carry on. If the message length > '0', then an error must have occured in the form processing, and it traps there to deal with it. However, when testing, I found that a successful processing of my form data, returned a message of size 13, even though the message itself was blank.

The javascript function I used is below. I have modified it to test for a message length of more than 13 characters, and this is working fine now. I' am just curious as to why a blank response is 13 characters in length. Ignore the complicated .load() statements, they just return the user to a different page depending on whether an error message was detected or not.

```
$("button#update").click(function() {
    var cat = $("select#cat_select").val();
    var dataString = $("form#project_update").serialize();
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "process.php",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: 'text', 
      success: function( msg ) {
        console.log('msg is ' + msg);
        length = msg.length;
        console.log('length is ' + length);
        if (length > 13) { // no idea why a blank msg has a length of 13!!
          alert(msg);
          $("#main").load('?app=$app&func=$func&sub=ajax&ajaxSub=edit_project&cat=' + cat + '&proj_id=' + $proj_id).fadeIn('fast');
        }
        else {
          $("#main").load('?app=$app&func=$func&sub=ajax&ajaxSub=project_detail&cat=' + cat + '&proj_id=' + $proj_id).fadeIn('fast');
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: probably in some case your response print some blank characters and/or newlines due to some line breaks on your php source code (and they are just 13 bytes)

Comment: What exactly gets logged in console/alerted? Note: use `console.log(msg)` instead of `console.log('string' + msg)`

Comment: make sure there are no spaces at all before <?php ?> and after and the entire code should be inside a single tag without any blank echos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
length = msg.length;
```

try with

```
length = msg.replace(/\s/g,'').length
```

#### Note

But you should make sure that there are no spaces or newlines within `<?php` and `?>` tags, I would be better if you remove them.

Comment: That's worked. A successful post is now returning a message length 0 as expected. Thanks.

Comment: I don't like this solution. Even if it works, one should address where those spaces come from, not elaborating on a solution that is, in fact, a "hack" on a not-working code.
If you expect that the spaces should not be there, they shouldn't be...

Comment: @Cranio problem to solution is first. but I added note in the solution. It's absolutely OP's choice, I think you shouldn't left comment to me.

Comment: Agreed, you're right. Removing my downvote after reconsidering your fair point.

Answer (score 0):

Check for hard-coded spaces outside your `<?php` and `?>` tags. I suppose the script calls itself via ajax, right?

Comment: Correct. The PHP script calls itself and the other URL parameters direct it to the relevant part of the code to execute.

Comment: I would have separated the logics, but I have not seen your code so the decision may be legit. But the risk to have unclean code in a script coded this way is very high.
You'll have to check where the spaces come from, also in the bits OUTSIDE the PHP code (it's easy in AJAX pages to leave trailing spaces or newlines outside the <? ?> tags.

Comment: I agree with you and will investigate where the extra spaces are coming from, now I know that it was extra spaces causing the issue in the first place. I've used thecodepardox's answer to prove where the issue lies, and will tidy up the code generating those extra spaces in due course. Thanks for your feedback.